# aws cognito verify sub of a newly signed up user

Tags: amazon-cognito

For a newly signed up user using Cognito Javascript SDK, it looks like we can get the 'sub' value, as per https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/335#issuecomment-307523556

If I pass this 'sub' value to my backend to initialize this user in the database, what's the best way to verify if this is a newly signed up valid user's sub?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you wanna check if the sub belongs to a valid user? In your backend, you can use listUsers based on sub.